# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface

Tags: magento2, error, di

When I try to update magento 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 I am getting this error

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php**

I try to edit **`app/etc/dl.xml`** but I am not getting what to update in preference type

Comment: You just need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to fix that error.

Comment: terminal showing same error when I try to upgrade

Comment: Post your di.xml and ovveride class both

Comment: I add this in di.xml <preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface" /> then I got error Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Circular type preference: Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface relates to Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface and viceversa.

Comment: anyone know what type should be there in that di.xml code